# Iraqi citizen traveling to Romania - do I need a transit visa in Turkey?

Tags: visas, transit, turkey, iraqi-citizens

I am an Iraqi citizen living in Cyprus and I want to travel with my wife who is Romanian to Romania 3 weeks later.

What I want to ask is whether or not I need a transit visa in Turkey considering the fact that Turkey doesn't issue visas for Iraqis anymore.

Comment: Are you transiting through a Turkish airport or traveling by land through Turkey?

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends what type of Iraqi passport you have.  I honestly haven't come across such a thing before, but am guessing it's post regime-change or something.

From [Timaticweb](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IQ&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=TR&user=EK&subuser=EMIRATES:):

> - Admission and transit refused to holders of Iraqi "S" series   passports.

So if you have one of those, you may have an issue getting in.

However:

> - Holders of normal passports issued to nationals of Iraq
>     arriving at Istanbul Ataturk (IST) and Sabiha Gokcen (SAW),   Adana
>     (ADA), Ankara (ESB), Antalya (AYT) or Gaziantep (GZT)   who have been
>     unable to apply for their e-Visa online at   www.evisa.gov.tr can
>     obtain an e-Visa on arrival at e-Visa   kiosks, for a max. stay of 30
>     days. Free of charge

So basically, avoid S series passports (if that's possible).

In addition there are some requirements about having a Latin alphabet passport and more, so do have a look at the details for more information.

Comment: I did not know about it either but it was apparently covered in the media: http://www.aljazeera.com/news/middleeast/2007/03/2008525173159185726.html and http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/middle_east/6474597.stm